# Log network traffic to an Azure VM even when stopped

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I want to know the idle time for a VM, that is when there are no web connection/RDP requests for say, one hour. I can log the traffic when the VM is running, but I want to log traffic when VM is stopped so that I can turn the VM back on when there's an incoming request after having been turned off.

I have looked into NSG flow Logs and packet capture. However, these options seem to only work when a VM is in running state.

Comment: Network logging is not free. You will probably find it less expensive to leave the VM running. If the VM has a public IP address, there will be enough noise traffic to defeat your strategy.

Comment: We have a number of VM's in different subscriptions. If there is a tool to log traffic at subscription/vnet level, wouldn't there be an effective cost saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TrueSight console you can view the Idle time of Azure VM. To know the idle time of VM Please refer this [Document](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/btco113/idle-virtual-machines-page-in-the-azure-virtual-machines-view-777740499.html#IdleVirtualMachinespageintheAzureVirtualMachinesview-ViewingdetailedinformationaboutaVM).

Your VM should up and running when you want to log the traffic. You can not log the traffic when VM is stopped because no traffic will reach out to VM if your VM is stop or shutdown.

Comment: Is it possible to get logs of incoming requests to a VM if I place it behind a load balancer. Would Azure load balancer have those logs available?

Comment: You can monitor and collect the data the is passing through the load balancer please do refrer this MS document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/monitor-load-balancer